# Flutter scope of context instance

Tags: dart, flutter

Referring to an official [Flutter tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#5), how is `context` referable in 
the `_pushSaved()` function?

```dart
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  ...
  void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the context of the state provided by `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Is it an instance of the class then? I failed to access it from the constructor.

Comment: The context is available when and after `initState()` is called. So it is not yet available in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to Flutter docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

The State class has a `context` property which is an instance of `BuildContext`

Hence you are able to refer `context` in your RandomWordsState class which extends State class